# Generalized Linear Model instead of log transformation

Tags: generalized-linear-model, modeling, data-transformation

I'm studying factors affecting the accuracy of taxpayers' perceptions of their own marginal income tax rates. The dependent variable (DV) is the misperception in percentage points. It ranges from 0 (i.e. accurate perception) to 35 (i.e. 35 percentage points mis-estimated). The frequency distribution is positively skewed because many more individuals make small estimation errors while fewer make larger errors. The independent variables (IV) are mainly categorical (e.g. whether the individual prepares his/her own tax return) except for one IV (taxable income) which is scale data. Initially, I had planned to use a log-linear model, with transformation of the DV by taking log (y+1) to deal with the zeros in the DV. However, I've read from many posts here and elsewhere that this is not ideal. Besides, the regression coefficients will not be amenable to an intuitive interpretation. Could anyone advise if this analysis could be carried out using a Generalized Linear Model   instead or am I totally off-tangent here to consider that? Any pointers to set me in the right direction are very much welcomed!

Comment: Is there a reason you are using the magnitudes of the misperceptions and ignoring their signs?  One would think there is a substantial difference between being 5 percentage points low versus 5 percentage points high.  A great deal of the difficulty in analyzing these data will stem from this decision to ignore the sign.

Comment: The signed errors, while less positively skewed than the absolute errors, were still non-normal because tax rates in the country involved (Singapore) are low and overestimations (mean 8.06 percentage points) substantially dominate underestimations (mean 3.41). Transformation would still be required but now with the added problem of not just zero values but also negative values. Hence, I decided to analyze the direction of misperception separately using descriptive statistics and to model the absolute errors.

Comment: Besides, if the signed errors were modeled, there would be offsetting effects from the underestimations and overestimations on the regression coefficients of the IVs.

Comment: Non-normality should not be an overriding consideration! (Moreover, the normality of these observations is unlikely to be relevant to almost any analysis you undertake.) Of fundamental importance is measuring what is relevant for your study: if that is not done, everything can be fatally flawed no matter how sophisticated your statistical methods are. In this case it's likely that the *relative* difference between what a taxpayer expects and what they pay is a good measure. If that happens to be signed and/or not normal or anything else, there are plenty of statistical cures for that.

Comment: But the regression residuals (whether using the signed or absolute errors, i.e. untransformed) are not normal (and heteroscedastic as well). While I can deal with the heteroscedasticity by re-estimating to obtain adjusted std errors of the beta weights, what should I do about the non-normal residuals?

Comment: It depends on how non-normal the residuals are, on how you are using the regression results, and on how much data you have. Residuals are rarely close to normal and many procedures are fairly robust to small departures from normality. In your application I would be inclined to interpret non-normality as evidence of lack of appropriate covariates and/or of highly nonlinear relationships. This suggests you might consider incorporating more variables in your model if you possibly can and you certainly should evaluate interaction terms and conduct goodness of fit tests.